# Randomly select elements of lists containing tuples?

Tags: python, list, random

I have a list containing single items and tuples of "subitems" as follows:

```py
items = ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', 'item_4', ('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_6', ('item_7a', 'item_7b')]
```

I now want to select `n` (here 4) number of items from said list, for example using `np.random.choice`:

```py
>>> np.random.choice(items, 4, replace=False)
array([('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_6', ('item_7a', 'item_7b'), 'item_4'],
      dtype=object)
```

This works but it considers tuples as one item. What im looking for is:

- Keep the items within a tuple grouped – always select together
- Select `n` items including "subitems" in a tuple

Something like this:

```py
>>> choose_n_items(items, 4, replace=False)
array([('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_6', 'item_4'],
      dtype=object)
```

Is there some inbuilt function with this functionality.

Comment: there is no magic builtin way to do this ... you will need to just select one item at a time, check the length, repeat until you have enough items

Comment: @JoranBeasley What if you're at a dead end, like you need one more item and  only have pairs left?

Comment: thats called programming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in solution as I'm aware of.

You can do something like this:

Basically you count tupel as the number of elements it contains and only add them if there is enough space.

```
import random
random.seed(1) # In case you want to control the output

items = ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', 'item_4', ('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_6', ('item_7a', 'item_7b')]

def random_choice(original_choice_list,n,replace=True):
    list_length = sum(map(lambda x: len(x) if isinstance(x,tuple) else 1,original_choice_list))
    choice_list = original_choice_list.copy()
    output = []
    actual_n = 0
    if not replace and n > list_length:
        raise ValueError("List has only {} elements but you want {}. With replace = False not possible".format(list_length,n))
    while actual_n < n:
        if not choice_list:
            return random_choice(original_choice_list, n, replace)
        item = random.choice(choice_list)
        if isinstance(item,tuple):
            if len(item) + actual_n <= n:
                output.append(item)
                actual_n += len(item)
        else:
            output.append(item)
            actual_n += 1
        if not replace:
            choice_list.remove(item)
    return output
for i in range(5):
    print(random_choice(items,4,replace=False))

print("######")

for i in range(5):
    print(random_choice(items,4,replace=True))
```

## Output

```
['item_2', 'item_6', 'item_1', 'item_3']
['item_4', ('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_6']
['item_6', 'item_4', 'item_2', 'item_1']
['item_4', 'item_1', 'item_6', 'item_2']
['item_6', 'item_4', 'item_3', 'item_2']
#####
[('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_1', 'item_3']
['item_1', 'item_1', 'item_1', 'item_6']
[('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_1', 'item_4']
['item_6', 'item_2', 'item_4', 'item_6']
['item_1', ('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_2']
```

Comment: @BBQuercus I had 2 small bugs: Because I didn't remove the item if it's not a tuple and because I didn't copy the list it didn't work (tuple could only draw once and strings could draw multiple times in one choice)

Comment: edit: Added replace (True with replacement, false without)

Comment: Ask for 8 items instead of 4 and watch your code crash.

Comment: @StefanPochmann do the same with numpy and it will crash as well. So why should i be better than numpy?

Comment: If you take `replace=False`then how can he add 8 elements, if you use replace=True it works.

Comment: What do you mean how can he add 8 elements? There are **9** elements, that's enough. So for example add all items except `item_1`. For a simpler case and one where you crash but numpy doesn't, try `items = [1, (2, 3)]` and ask for 2 items.

Comment: @StefanPochmann hmm yeah I see the problem thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Ok :-). I don't think this is easy, it's like a [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) in disguise.

Comment: @StefanPochmann yeah at the moment I have two "stupid" solutions like if this happens => do it again until it works (don't like that one but is would be the "easiest") and the other add it into the list and at the end remove items so that the length is correct again hmm... not sure how this would affect the randomness

Comment: Yeah, randomness is another issue. Like, should a long tuple have the same or higher probability than a shorter tuple or a single item? OP would need to tell us.

Comment: I think the randomness should come from each item/subitem – therefore longer strings would have higher probabilities. In my use case however, the longest tuple 'only' has a size of 4 (50-60 total items)

Comment: Right now I have implemented that it will run again in case the elements doesn't fit. This error would only happen if your n is big but with this it shouldn't happen anymore (maybe not the best solution but it works).
Hmm at the moment tuple have the same chance of getting picked then a normal element. In case that a tuple needs nx the chance to getting picked (depending of their length) I have to change the selection.

Comment: I think this implementation should work more than good enough. If things don't work out I at least know where to begin :)

Comment: So far I've managed to make you go to recursion depth 445 (around 1000 you might crash) and the `replace=True` case appears to be in an infinite loop: https://repl.it/repls/PolishedSpectacularCondition

Comment: Ok I tried that with different seeds, and seed 66 makes it crash (with RecursionError).

Comment: @StefanPochmann yeah I see the problem. In case that it's hard to return the exact number of elements it will take a long while and in case of replace=True it will change into an infinite loop. The problem may be harder than anticipated in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

items = ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', 'item_4', ('item_5a', 'item_5b'), 'item_6', ('item_7a', 'item_7b')]
output= []
n=4
counter = 0
while counter <4:
    for index, i in enumerate(np.random.randint(0, len(items),n)): 
        tuple_count=0 
        if counter >=4:
            break
        if items[i].__class__==tuple:
            print("in tuple")                
            if (index in range(0,n-2)) and tuple_count<=2:                    
                counter +=len(items[i])
                tuple_count +=1
                output.append(items[i])               

        else:
            counter +=1
            output.append(items[i])

print(output)
```

Comment: doesn't work. In case your output already has 3 elements and the last element you add is a tuple you have a length of 5 instead of 4. In addition you have with replacement and in case the tuple has more than 2 elements it won't work neither.

Comment: you still have duplicates